# Properly check if a record already exists in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have read other questions on this, but it does not help for the most part.
Trying to check if a file has already been uploaded(filename is sent to this table) before creating another record and allowing them to upload the same file again.

I am using this code and it keeps telling me every file is a new file, even when I use the same file for testing. Obviously it should result in "Exists". Connection is already established using "this.Master.Conn" so please no SQLCommand stuff.

I even tried using wildcards in the query.

```
   private string SQLCheck(string FileName)
{
    string Check = "Select VideoURL from TrainingVideo2 where VideoURL Like '" + FileName +"' and Status=1;";

    Object ob = this.Master.Conn.ExecuteSqlScalarCommand(Check);
    string Result;
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(ob))
    {
        Result = "Exists";
    }
    else
    {
        Result = "NewFile";
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Also, does anybody have a better(more efficient) way of doing this?

Trying to basically rewrite this in c#.

```
    Private Function CheckName(name As String) As Int32
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID FROM Company Where Name Like '" & name & "' "
    Dim ob As Object = Conn.ExecuteSqlScalarCommand(sql)
    If IsDBNull(ob) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return CInt(ob)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think, you should reverse the condition, when file does not present, it will result in `null` , compare with `dbnull`, so even if file does not present, it will say `exists`, as you are checking `DBNull.Value.Equ..`

Comment: Don't ever return a string in place of a true/false value. Your method should return a bool.

Comment: Also use parameterized query instead of concatenated string, it is a big security hole for sql injection

Comment: Seems like a strange way to solve the security issue. Must be a lot easier to always use parameters than to review all code to ensure  single and double-quotes are removed everywhere. It is not like writing code to use parameters is more difficult or takes more time than using concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are new and more innovative methods devised to get around the simple "replace all ` and " characters with ..." SQL injection prevention techniques. In your case, if the VideoURL happens to be a varchar (and not nvarchar), then using unicode character `U+02BC` (URL encoded = `%CA%BC`) would pass in a quote character as a unicode string, which would bypass your C# checks, but SQL Server will conveniently convert to a quote character in your query. This is just one example of why you should not be doing this :).

In terms of you check, I always prefer using `TOP 1` to let SQL Server cut a potential table scan short. So, I would use this query:

```
Select TOP 1 SomeNonNullIntColumn from TrainingVideo2 where VideoURL Like ... and Status=1;
```

Execute the query with ExecuteScalar. If the result is `null`, then the record does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Never build up an SQL string like that. See [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Why are you using `like`? Do you really have Sql wildcards in that `fileName`?

Example (sorry for the "`SqlCommand` stuff", but it's important):

```
string sql = "select count(*) from TrainingVideo2 where VideoURL = @Name and Status=1"
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", fileName);
    conn.Open();
    return (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need new senior programmers.  Parameterized queries are the way to prevent SQL injection, not scrubbing values.